# How can I access images into plugin in cakephp 2.*?

Tags: image, cakephp, plugins

I saved my plugin images in here:

```
app/plugin/my-plugin-name/webroot/img/...
```

now :
I want to access theme same as $this->Html->image(path)
what is your plan for this?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$this->Html->image('My-Plugin-Name.image.png');
```

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image

Answer (score 1):

When I need to include a CSS from a folder outside CSS, I use this, it may work in your case

```
$this->Html->image(array('../../plugin/my-plugin-name/webroot/img/imagename');
```

Anyway, you can also use absolute routes

```
$this->Html->image(APP . 'plugin/my-plugin-name/webroot/img/imagename');
```

Comment: Thank you SkarXa. but dhofstet's answer is better and more useful.